# HTML5 Video Buffered не правильное срабатывание onprogress в Firefox

Tags: javascript, html5

Получаю значение буферизации следующей функцией по событию `progress`

```
function buffered(video) {
    if(video.duration > 0) {
        for(var i = 0; i < video.buffered.length; i++) {
            if(video.buffered.start(video.buffered.length - 1 - i) < video.currentTime) {
                var buffered = (video.buffered.end(video.buffered.length - 1 - i) / video.duration) * 100;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return buffered;
}
```

В Webkit браузерах всё нормально, но в Firefox событие либо не срабатывает, либо не всегда, в любом случае ведёт себя не так как в Webkit. В том же Chrome буферизация точно совпадает с стандартным плеером Chrome, в Firefox нет.

Firefox 65.0.2